# Magento Admin Configuration Not Saving In Database

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

System -> Configurations -> General -> Countries Options

I am trying to save Default Country, Allowed Countries. When i hit submit it shows me it saved but when i come back again to see the configurations it has nothing that i saved.

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 and I installed a fresh install.

Comment: Check exception.log and system.log file, if there is any error. You can enable error logging from  System->Configuration->Developer->Log Setting and make var/log/ directory writable.

Comment: @RajivRanjan I have noticed its only not working with default store view. Its saving data when i change the main site configuration .... what would be the issue then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking into code, not able to solve the issue.

But, you can update the Default Country, Allowed Countries value from data base side. Below the SQL Query to get all rows of General tab -> Countries Options and edit from here.

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%general_country%';
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 8):

Just faced with the same problem.

The problem was that we activated ssl in apache but Use Secure URLs option in magento still remains equal to No.

I found next workaround:

```
- go to System -> Configuration -> Web
- change Use Secure URLs in Admin to Yes
- open firebug in firefox
- find form node in html
- change action from http://... to https://...
- submit form
```

Answer (score 0):

My case was a little different, I could find the following error:

```
PHP Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0, referer: (url)
```

This particular page had a lot of input fields, changing `max_input_vars` did the trick